# What is the probability that at least one of these three will function for at least 47 months?

Tags: probability

A fictional company produces coffee makers. If T is the random variable representing the lifetime, in months, of one of these coffee makers, 
the probability density function p(x) of T is given by the formula p(x) = 0 if x ≤ 15 and p(x) = 15 / x^2 if x > 15.

Suppose that we now have 3 coffee makers produced by the same company, and that they operate 
completely independently of each other. What is the probability that at least one of these three will function for at least 47 months?

So... I already calculated the probability of ONE coffee maker lasting for at least 47 months (15/47) , but how do I account for at least one of three of them to work?

Comment: do those probabilities even add up to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: probability at least one machine works $= 1 -$ probability that all fail.

Can you see why? You should be able to answer the question from here.

Comment: Right, I did know that rule.
So, to figure out the probability of one failing you would take 1 - (15/47) = (32/47)
Then you would take (32/47) ^ 3
Then subtract that value from 1?